# What Library? [first puzzle]

Tags: cipher

ywfwkak 33:21

```
38t762izu3rpv2cnghy6plwihwokoo3x4l9dtukk4a37tulvx95giwa481ah7hy7dtgoc3c4dy6z3tjzvsyzjqpvlhav2x4xzywyoycdzsunkk1wkutdwztt7bkzayc3yrxtgitw9eygp4k70s5c2tcy2tr9a0jl4b1e4ick559mau2kvsq9mdcqrzocxpfeo2hf1k1o2l3deu10jo5vfe122zrcxxk0x4zf85cgmn99mji83sui8gz2e9jrlordaz7eo3tnjnof8acpk9jcggjvwmd09smeqw5kgtjuwkrr4glwg01w5cmwtaa2h9yuk57qimstmq3d4yrya040phfw9629k76ao84t169msld85m8qndl20ai7c0njpeoa43hvs5upho51pm052mgf41p3c5857k8t513hr9ipqendlzo2t9rcxmuidawv22f9z0y72eg580m0yznl9ptdbw1dgwap4e63p6usesyfk4vurtzdjr2u6bs0pbqwdzymfmcf64hynytdophmkqe34tro2vocmdg98snj8g865hjagttak40pzg2ixr5o0d4thzci2abrdaceslybu9hqr0dyg4frtetqlev74qltgc5h5mop69965mjtki5ev9qhs9mncyylbudroo5nscx3x84x0i6ntwtq5ussna0t4ic5f5zscyvkybbccvcgpioffts7613vlzcgw1knh4ad7ezpq4un56s34cx2uz242600i80ihno23kub4hjbk3ginin34og5zeblgvv29h4fbndf19ibr62fjmrff3gdjiv95gnvxzvcth64z8ba4p5rj4y1os2uu3y3s6gqp5a5lt0662rzb5pb9fbzpsqawheb88o6q6hoq4ax804bmicwn7b8l6yep494ndvhlyzhd7s1au53ulh67ud6gy3v29s30dnzd66a6qak3oobrtto3ww11c6xg7kkhf1ctsrqggtnoszfjl3501ms1pfc3cqluvcsnc3wwz85x9jr8lfn2rsdbcrjndcwtizlf5bxfwrp9e5zium4depcsbez841k6yalbnrbq9sk7dy1phh8kmybd0xludf8mrj3lwmiltcv0ntyf78ky644p7no29jzvq4q4esmll3ssa25lqkw6o8a6pv7h9bwu4tivd9guj0cn4wsjwd4vzhqthux9sqc13f6hyrgfqyusymwp2pl44wdf4vn580bobx547838y9borx14lvd603omu3j0nzxtcwu595tgli1md86nign3prbfuok9i95630trj6zm92dp09v852efop3ly52dx9a82wm7wuh4dx3bmcxrebj1wxcmdg7g8wc9yohwr7vnsie95hfwo50rraua5lr1gmii4i67v4u31ftps37kql3xmkqkxoatohqafu5oufykop4yo7p9czktdbvsbqx4wa3gzl9elsgyotbqiwvw7np4m26s3mtrps4kuroj28ewkv5eds1lhw96iap5zyq76m6528mrzav5eb5csioa4ihizcgwqqk3811afsqid84a38f61s3oxxay6kp686t0ejxnal1tupvnklyhryvxi1plqistkcgmqf77x96jhatc3di1dihcy56d47rss6w1ox355oh7z0jzrmlg9hw05rf0rmdgkb7wzx95npd4lnmqnax6kgvt44canmjf7a9vx482bak5h0l5snzpq788chhjqsicnl97wpvnq4fk6h9c18jls5ntmvbe28sqh93quuzzhktxz6alc2l8zwvvdw12kxm05d8x5jrt7hbrm4az8qak2rsj5od2n52urh82zurilwrln1qo1y8t2e1hcaxlo5e3g5d4cr7cawr7oazuroevcq15pmgbvjp8dhml4xhs37pt7g2ubjm7kbtsyfhc7bqpqa7luloi8l066fqzeriyktn2xk4a2eooddwciw4fchpxe9ldfxnc5vvxh8jz4waszcfrqidkoghixbsslvxnw44sv3s26kb32zzogasi5qlne3ag5agr8tat3knns43qv66f928tft1zthy9gul2g6newvyptuimy4n0f3lx69pcxd13ref04albtexmn5at159c53t6bth5cvj23bgjhqp1b50kikdm0v1r5szul80vx2sj9x3fe9913f3nsq8xip0wqkx7bhvx6o6dsd291j1cbu2l0w34aawu3p9vj4wmzz8gb6iufqs5jbyxkex1uo9nwet2v0llz3pq41688mx41mbixtvg7vhbqh3bfjd8mxyvot10u8mpxybna6a1nii5dryzbnnick5qg4mwq2lgim8uiaigf5je7dh1rl7p60660yajhkk3aq5wpp6hl3895z1qz1pyoivl4kz606tjn7zd6kyokf82dnh8nl36jwpqhbpm8f6u27y5oksj6rpumqne2rfgn213kjg8ni5312qoki347e5utg2riqdw3zv7jbco29qz2lxb0xddmuhvee4kxkbbzf8z47gsyhialgo9usk1wmz5vw9w20ee5yrx2ri47zmmykxk7ujwsybg3hldy8thw1suih7bxy4gy4fzjbig4gw6hwo22l9wn6wuniqrr0ezmh7ev2c3yk2ekwfgd261sxfiz4bggbekbnfpowu6ieex269jbckixrbl1hc6dnk49xpl7kfb4snl0u61eps4u2l9mhem88w5pmp4iq296hawgzso7z4gfgh77hu6t8x9i1knnt8764t82hgirqza35mygbhf4bh93r5a7hs6obn893z7pxahuqwoe1khhsp61hhcjojokckxz9y4e3lqybnj1m507ej3i1cu300wks89hkcpp198nwmgirpu366urtangdodu3zu5zjj4j6ws65n9536es4ay7qzq4iggbzn06yfbev68clkbqmuo382s5ghmpo8a95xuditiyh3ummbcoa9okovewoywkmnu8tlyeo4ug80ki1labzjcnng6jswr4rx1esqpoahje394r875fhp2yl60t905akyhb3788w0gjhyeqzk5yoxpgo3x7qhdrv01lnrht0eu345ae2rr8rapleh95cw257jb54lwzi48q8wo6840wn066w97pjfvvbxe05x50mbg9jhztimpl5fdos951myuvsssgr02fhuncwc1ty8ztu314idy55gte4pwuk75f9o8lmpqqgas5p09u13hp9lt6kj20l6a9ay4djks3c9a
```

1
2
pskbtwecxvcoqbb,sl .ogmgr
166

This is my first puzzle so any feedback is welcome. Everything you need to find the answer is here.

Comment: Thanks and welcome. Looks like an interesting one

Comment: Rot8: Ywfwkak 33 gfdq zsk 20 nwjkwk.

Comment: @DrXorile rot8: uzwuc gml lzwtdgt jgl wfugvwj/vwugvwj

Comment: Hey, nice username @Brandon

Comment: Seeing that long string of base32 immediately made me think of a Library of Babel Hex Address. So I could have skipped the first step easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. > ywfwkak 33:21 => Rot8 (including numbers) = Genesis 11:09
2. > Going to Genesis 11:09 we see:
   >  *"That is why it was called **Babel** — because there the Lord confused the language of the whole world. From there the Lord scattered them over the face of the whole earth."*
   >
   >  Using the clue from the title, I searched for **Library of Babel**
3. > When we go to [Library of Babel](https://libraryofbabel.info/) we use the browse tab to search for 38t762izu3rpv2...
4. > Now, we can use the next clues that tell us to go to Wall 1, Shelf 2, Volume with the name "pskbtwecxvcoqbb,sl" .ogmgr and Page 166
5. > Now we get:
   >  **congratulations, you made it, the answer is
   >
   >  ioioiiioooioioioooioooioiiioioioooioooioioioooioioioooooooioiiioiiioioooioooioii 
   >  ioioooioioioooioioooioioioooiiioooioooiiioioooiiioioiiioioooio
   >
   >
   >
   >  www.youtube.com watch
   >
   >  cap h, cap y, underscore, cap o, cap i, w, i, d, e, cap l, g
   >
   >  min fourteen sec twenty**
6. > Going to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY_OIwideLg Minute 14, Second 20 there is an explanation on how to decode the answer.
7. > After translating io=.(dot), oo= (sep) and iiio=-(dash) we get morse code:
   >  ..- ... . .-.. . ... ...   .--. . .-. ... .. ... - . -. -.-. .
8. > Translating the morse code we finally get the answer: **USELESS PERSISTENCE**

Comment: You are so close!

Comment: @pirate perhaps binary?

Comment: rot13: Rirelguvat ba gur cntr vf vzcbegnag, vg zvtug uryc vs lbh xabj gur punenpgre pbafgenvagf sbe gur yvoenel bs Onory

Comment: @Brandon Think I got it now